# Подстановка параметра PreparedStatement в JDBC Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Столкулся с тем, что данная конструкция подстановки параметра (:1) работает с драйвером Oracle:

```
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        try (Connection con =
                 DriverManager.getConnection("HOST", "USER", "PASS")) {
            try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement =
                     con.prepareStatement("select * from TABLE where name = :1")) {
                preparedStatement.setString(1, "NAME");
                try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        System.out.println(resultSet.getObject(1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

В JSR указано использование только знака ?.
Это особенность реализации драйвера?

UPD:

Версия БД:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

Что замечено еще:

```
    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement =
             con.prepareStatement("select * from TABLE where name = :abc and id = :dcf")) {
        preparedStatement.setString(1, "PARAM");
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, 173);
        try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getObject(1));
            }
        }
    }
```

просьба обратить внимание на название подстановок, этот код работает.
А вот этот уже не работает:

```
    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement =
             con.prepareStatement("select * from TABLE  where name = :abc and id = :dcf")) {
        preparedStatement.setString(2, "NAME");
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, 173);
        try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getObject(1));
            }
        }
    }

    java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: неверное число
```

То есть на название вообще нет реакции, только на ":" порядок.

Comment: Я переработал ответ. Посмотрите, отвечает ли он на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Исчерпывающий ответ, спасибо огромное )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> В JSR указано использование только знака ?.

Символ `?` это ещё не подстановочный параметр, это только местозаполнитель (*placeholder*), все символы местозаполнители функция `prepareStatement()` 
заменит на подстановочные переменные (или переменные связывания (*bind variables*)) используя синтаксис для подстановочных переменных целевой СУБД.

Если в SQL выражении указать подстановочные параметры сразу в том виде, в котором на целевой СУБД выполнится подготовка и компиляция (*parse*), то функция `prepareStatement()` не призведёт никакой замены и не заметит, что её "лишили работы".

> Это особенность реализации драйвера?

Да, или лучше сказать - это особенность целевой СУБД, которую этот драйвер поддерживает. 
Касательно подстановочных переменных, различные СУБД имеют различный синтаксис этих переменных:

- Oracle: `:var` (*colon*)
- MySQL, DB2 and Firebird: `?` (*question marks*)
- Sybase, MS SQL Server: `@var` (*at sign*)
- PostgreSQL: `$var` (*dollar sign*)

Для подтверждения вышесказанного, рассмотрим следующий пример.

Выполним один и тот же запрос несколько раз с различным использованием местозаполнителей и подстановочных параметров:

```
create or replace and compile java source named TestPrepared as
import java.sql.*;
public class TestPrepared {
    public static void selectValue (int id, String item) {
        String[] stmts = {
            /*#1*/"/* ? */ select id, item from items where id = ? and item = ?",
            /*#2*/"/* ? */ select id, item from items where id = :1 and item = :2",
            /*#3*/"/* ? */ select id, item from items where id = :2 and item = :3",
            /*#4*/"/* ? */ select id, item from items where id = :id and item = :item"};
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbsrv:1521/pdb1","sh","sh");
            for (int i=0; i<stmts.length; i++) {
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(stmts[i]);
                ps.setInt (1, id);
                ps.setString (2, item);
                ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    System.out.println("id=" + resultSet.getObject(1) + ",item=" +  resultSet.getObject(2));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
/
create or replace procedure selectValue (id number, item varchar2) as
language java name 'TestPrepared.selectValue (int, java.lang.String)';
/
exec selectValue (2, 'item2')

id=2,item=item2
id=2,item=item2
id=2,item=item2
id=2,item=item2
```

Какие SQL выражения были посланы на БД сервер:

```
select sql_id, parse_calls parses, substr (sql_text,1,78) text 
from  v$sql
where parsing_schema_name = user and sql_text like '/*%' 
;
SQL_ID        PARSES TEXT                                                                         
------------- ------ -------------------------------------------------------------------
dvc53b7ugwu0q      1 /* :1 */ select id, item from items where id = :1 and item = :2               
8zbzysz5m53wf      2 /* :1 */ select id, item from items where id = :2 and item = :3               
872ztnzx59hm8      1 /* :1 */ select id, item from items where id = :id and item = :item
```

В исходном SQL выражении #1 функция `prepareStatement()` произвела замену местозаполнителей `?` на подстановочные переменные `:1, :2, :3`. В #3 замены не произошло (не считая в комментарии). Оба SQL выражения, #1 и #3, полностью совпали и рассматриваются БД сервером как одно, подготовленное и скомпилированное (`parses=2`) SQL выражение.

> То есть на название вообще нет реакции, только на ":" порядок.

Да, в JDBC стандарте важен только порядок (*bind by index*). В коде вопроса, к которому эта цитата относится, порядок нарушен, что привело к ошибке. В расмотренном выше примере, замена произведена учитывая только порядок (т.е. по индексу), какие имена/номера стояли после символа `:` не сыграло никакой роли.

Если интересна подстановка по имени (*bind by name*), то как упомянуто в [оф. документации гл. Binding by name](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/apxref.htm#JJDBC28929)

> This capability to bind by name using the setXXX methods is not part of the JDBC specification, and Oracle does not support it.

Oracle не поддерживает подстановку по имени при использовании метода, как в вопросе, `setString()`. То есть в стандартном JDBC интерфейсе `PreparedStatement` это не поддерживается.

Но можно воспользоваться, например, расширением к этому интерфейсу [OraclePreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OraclePreparedStatement.html):

```
create or replace and compile java source named TestPreparedOra as
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.*;
public class TestPreparedOra
{
    public static void selectValue (int id, String item) {
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");
            OraclePreparedStatement ps = (OraclePreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement (
                "select id, item from items where item = :item and id = :id");
            ps.setStringAtName("item", item);
            ps.setIntAtName(   "id",   id);
            ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println("id=" + resultSet.getObject(1) + ",item=" +  resultSet.getObject(2));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}    
/
create or replace procedure selectValueOraEx (id number, item varchar2) as
language java name 'TestPreparedOra.selectValue (int, java.lang.String)';
/
exec selectValueOraEx (2, 'item2')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

id=2,item=item2
```

Comment: В доке по вашей ссылке полезное упоминание о возможности явно использовать `setXXXAtName` методы: `"Starting from Oracle Database 10g JDBC drivers, bind by name is supported using the setXXXAtName methods."` - может стоит добавить в ответ?

Comment: Кстати никак не могу найти описания _нумерованных_ параметров (как у автора вопроса `:1`, `:2`) для JAVA - похоже это действительно особенность реализации драйвера от Oracle...

Comment: @MaxU Да тоже мысль была, но вопрос типа "почему так?", а не "как нужно?".

Comment: в общем да, если пройти по ссылке информация там есть ;)

Comment: @Мах Насколько я понял, это не нумерованные параметры, это _binds_, т.е. их по именам будет искать - `setStringAtName("1", "value")`.  А старые драйвера их сдуру по порядку подставляли.

Comment: это объясняет почему я не мог ничего найти :)

Comment: @MaxU обновил вопрос, привел пример, что имя ни на что не влияет

Comment: @0xdb спасибо за ответ, добавил информации в вопрос, сам вопрос так и остался открытым (

Comment: @ezhov_da Да, я посмотрел, примеры. Действительно, во всех версиях работает подстановка по индексу с `:` также, как и с `?`  Причём, имя не играет никакой роли, `:1 :a1 :name`, всё вроде работает.  "сам вопрос так и остался открытым (" - вы не могли бы его уточнить, что ожидается в ответе.

Comment: @0xdb идеальным ответом была бы ссылка на задокументированную возможность в этой части, так как сам не нашел, хотя честно, искал долго

Comment: @ezhov_da Тоже долго искал,  но пока, как в ссылке в ответе - "This capability to bind by name using the setXXX methods is not part of the JDBC specification" и "The JDBC drivers can throw a SQLException or produce unexpected results" - не специфицировано, не поддерживается и может привести к неожидаемым резултатам.